# how to render html content without any navigation into ng-view?

Tags: angularjs

I want to render html template to ng-view without changing navigation but based on user action. for eg: when user click on List button, i need to clear ng-view and display content related to list into ng-view. and when user click on create button then need to display content related to create in ng-view and when user click on view page, need to display content related to view in ng-view. but i dont want to use any navigation link to do that. i have enough buttons actions.I want to do this with Anugularjs without using jQuery. Any reply appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the content inside ng-view and not cause url change then  you need to use `ng-include` to dynamically load template based on the current state of the model\scope.

You define a parent view which is loaded in `ng-view` for the first time

```
<div id='parent' ng-controller='parentController'>
   <div ng-include='currentViewUrl'>
</div>
```

And in your `parentController` based on different conditions you would set the `currentViewUrl`

```
$scope.currentViewUrl='listView';
```

or

```
$scope.currentViewUrl='detailView';
```

These templates referenced by `currentViewUrl` can be either server side templates or can be loaded together into the main view using `ng-template`

Comment: ok thanks chandermani. one more doubt is every template may have their own controller to manage data. can we access those by parent controller also?

Comment: For shared data, the options are either to define it at the parent level and since scopes are inherited the child can access and change, or define service that share data among the controllers.